# KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access while creating and dropping globalTempView in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am running the below code and after reading couple of RDDs from Kafka I get this Kafka multithreding access error. Not sure what is causing this. Basically what code does is that it reads CDRs from kafka and tries to put that in a globaltempview. In short, all the RDDs / dataframes must be stored in global view. I am using Kafka 0.10 and spark 2.1.1

```
val  schema_string = "subscriberNumber, originNodeType, originHostName, originOperatorID, originTimeStamp, currentServiceClass, voucherBasedRefill, transactionAmount, refillProfileID, voucherGroupID, externalData1, externalData2"
val schema_rdd = StructType(schema_string.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)) )
 val init_df= sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema_rdd)

println("initial count of initial RDD is " +init_df.count())




init_df.createGlobalTempView("AIRGLOBAL")



AirDRStream.foreachRDD(foreachFunc = rdd => {
  System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.count() + " records");



  if (rdd.count() == 0) {
    println("--- No logs received in this time interval=================")

  } else {

    rdd.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("AIR")
    val FilteredDR = sqlContext.sql("select  * from AIR ")
    val globalview= sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM  global_temp.AIRGLOBAL ")
    println("RESULTS FROM GLOBAL VIEW before union"+ globalview.count() )
    globalview.union(FilteredDR).createOrReplaceTempView("TempView")



    sqlContext.catalog.dropGlobalTempView("AIRGLOBAL")
    println("global view dropped" )

    val tempview =sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM  TempView ")
    println("Results from tempView" + tempview.count() )


    tempview.createGlobalTempView("AIRGLOBAL")
    println("global view created after dropping"  )




    //val globalviewfinal= sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM  global_temp.AIRGLOBAL ")
    //println("RESULTS FROM GLOBAL VIEW after union"+ globalviewfinal.count() )





  }
})

streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

Below is full trace of errors. As you can see it runs fine for couple of RDDs and then throws error.

```
    ---creating Empty RDD
initial count of initial RDD is 0
--- New RDD with 0 records
--- No logs received in this time interval=================
--- New RDD with 1741 records
RESULTS FROM GLOBAL VIEW before union0
global view dropped
Results from tempView1741
global view created after dropping
RESULTS FROM GLOBAL VIEW after union1
--- New RDD with 4692 records
RESULTS FROM GLOBAL VIEW before union1741
global view dropped
Results from tempView6433
global view created after dropping
18/05/06 11:04:00 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 17)
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:1431)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1132)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.seek(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/05/06 11:04:00 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 18.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
18/05/06 11:04:00 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1525593840000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 18.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 17, localhost, executor driver): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:1431)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1132)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.seek(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1965)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2392)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2420)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2419)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2801)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2419)
        at com.asiacell.spark.KafkaAirDRsProcess$$anonfun$main$1.apply(KafkaAirDRsProcess.scala:113)
        at com.asiacell.spark.KafkaAirDRsProcess$$anonfun$main$1.apply(KafkaAirDRsProcess.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:255)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:1431)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1132)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.seek(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        ... 3 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 18.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 17, localhost, executor driver): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:1431)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1132)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.seek(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1965)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2392)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2420)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2419)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2801)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2419)
        at com.asiacell.spark.KafkaAirDRsProcess$$anonfun$main$1.apply(KafkaAirDRsProcess.scala:113)
        at com.asiacell.spark.KafkaAirDRsProcess$$anonfun$main$1.apply(KafkaAirDRsProcess.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:255)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:1431)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1132)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.seek(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
```

Answer (score 0):

KafkaConsumer has never intended to be thread-safe contrary to the producer.

Actually AFAIK most MQ consumers are not thread safe.

Anyway if you want to avoid the burden of writing Kafka Consumer specific code I have create a lib to avoid this :

https://www.github.com/jaubin/gojulmq4j-api

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure I will test that. But I am just reading from a single kafka topic and putting data temp views. How come its using multi threading? Can you please help me understand. Apart from your own api, is there any other tweaking which can be done to avoid this issue?

Comment: Well maybe the multithread mechanism is hidden, for example if you're using your consumer in a web server on a shared service.